# Change empty cells size in List in SwiftUI macOS 12

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

Is there a way to resize empty cell placeholders inside list? Explicitly setting List content height do nothing. Is it a bug? I want to match the style as Finder has.

```swift
List(items, selection: $selection) { item in
    ListCellView(description: item.description, date: item.date)
}
.listStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 58)
```

[image]